# What happens to players between missions?

Tags: the-world-ends-with-you

After completing each mission or goal for the day, Neku usually has a dialogue with his partner. Occasionally, some Reaper activity is shown. The day abruptly ends and the next day begins.

When the day begins, Neku's monologue always (particularly during the first few days) seems to indicate that he has no idea how he got to wherever he is.

Is there any information regarding where the players go after missions are completed or how/why they are suddenly transported back to the starting point in the morning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

During the first week, I notice that Neku seems a bit groggy or sleepy as certain days begin. (This may also happen on other occasions, but I only remember it being prominent during the first week.) This leads me to think that surviving Players are either sent to sleep or simply knocked out between one day's completion and the next day's beginning. It's also possible that they are locked in some manner of stasis, which would allow them to be transported (in some manner or another) from one location to another between days; this would explain why Neku typically stretches as he regains consciousness (or maybe the sprite was just reused for convenience, I don't know).

Considering that there's no actual footage of what happens between days, though, I'm sure you could just make something up and explain it away however you like.